# Matlab: Sort 2 cell matrices of strings

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have 2 cell matrices of strings that I want to compare and sort in one. For example:

```
Data1={'hello','daddy','mama';'0','55','60';'asd','','dwadsdwa'};

Data2={'cat','daddy','dog','cat','mama','daddy';'21','54','79','1','0','231';'sa','wda','thjd','gf','wda','sda'};
```

I want to compare the FIRST Row of the matrices and create a new result matrix with the matching elements and their columns. Like:

```
matches={'daddy','daddy','daddy','mama','mama';'55','54','231','60','0';'','wda','sda','dwadsdwa','wda'};
```

I tried with:

```
Da1Index=find(ismember(Data1(1,:),Data2(1,:)));
Firstmatches=Data1(:,Da1Index);

Da2Index=find(ismember(Data2(1,:),Data1(1,:)));
Secondmatches=Data2(:,Da2Index);
```

So I would get the matching elements and their columns in 2 other Cell matrices. Now I could search for every single name-element of Firstmatches in the Secondmatches cell Array, but I wonder if there's a better way?
Also I don't know how to add the columns to the right positions.

Maybe there is an easier way to do this? I hope it's clear what I want to achieve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
i1 = ismember(Data1(1,:), Data2(1,:));  %// columns of Data1 to keep
i2 = ismember(Data2(1,:), Data1(1,:));  %// columns of Data1 to keep
matches = [Data1(:,i1) Data2(:,i2)];    %// build result
matches = sortrows(matches.').';        %// sort if needed. Note: lexicographical order
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. But can you explain the sortrows(matches.').';  expression?  what is .').' doing?

Comment: `.'`is transpose. `sortrows` sorts the rows of the array, but you want to sort the columns. So you transpose, sort rows, and then transpose back